# Replicated AnnotatedTimeLine GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on a GUI which is coded under GWT framework. However, I have noticed about one malfunctioning and I don't know what the cause could be. Well, the idea is to print a set of similar tabs. Each tab contains an horizontal panel where the right side integrates an AnnotatedTimeLine object with the proper data. The code where the tabs are drawn is the following:

```
for(String sBuilding : lsBuildings){
    if(sBuilding.equals(BuildingCodes.getsTucBuildingCode())){  
        tabLayoutPanel.add(printScreen.printScreen(hmTucData, hmMonthTucData, "TUC"), "TUC offices", true);
    }
    else if(sBuilding.equals(BuildingCodes.getsCartifBuildingCode())){
        tabLayoutPanel.add(printScreen.printScreen(hmCartifData, hmMonthCartifData, "CARTIF"), "CARTIF offices", true);
    }
    else if(sBuilding.equals(BuildingCodes.getsZubBuildingCode())){
        tabLayoutPanel.add(printScreen.printScreen(hmZubData, hmMonthZubData, "ZUB"), "ZUB offices", true);
    }
    else if(sBuilding.equals(BuildingCodes.getsSierraBuildingCode())){
        tabLayoutPanel.add(printScreen.printScreen(hmSierraData, hmMonthSierraData, "SIERRA"), "Sierra Elvira School", true);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I add one tab depending on the data which I want to show (i.e. hmXXXXData and hmMonthXXXXData). Within the printScreen method is where I print the AnnotatedTimeLine as follows:

```
//If the data is not collected, no graph should be displayed
    if(hmMonthData.size() > 0){

        //Get the list of values of the sensors in the Zone visible in the stack panel
        final Map<String, Map<String,String>> hmSensorsByZone = hmMonthData.get(sSelectedZone);

        //Get the list of sensors associated to the Zone selected
        Object[] asSensors = hmSensorsByZone.keySet().toArray();

        //Only if the length of sensors is upper than 0
        if(asSensors.length > 0){

            final List<String> lsSensors = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i = 0; i < asSensors.length; i++){
                lsSensors.add(asSensors[i].toString());
            }

            // Chart for printing the trends of the last month for the variable
            Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {             
                    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
                    //Columnas a mostrar, la primera para el eje de abscisas (fecha) y la segunda para
                    //los valores en el eje de ordenadas
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");

                    for(String sSensor : lsSensors){
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, sSensor);
                    }

                    DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss");

                    //Se añaden los valores y los puntos para dibujar la gráfica
                    for(int j = 0; j < lsSensors.size(); j++){
                        //Delete all the rows related to the sensor j

                        Map<String,String> hmValues = hmSensorsByZone.get(lsSensors.get(j));

                        //Only if the size of the values is upper than 0
                        if(hmValues.size() > 0){

                            Object[] asTimestamps = (Object[]) hmValues.keySet().toArray(); 
                            Object[] asValues = (Object[]) hmValues.values().toArray(); 

                            if(data.getNumberOfRows() < asTimestamps.length)
                                data.addRows(asTimestamps.length - data.getNumberOfRows()); 

                            for(int i = 0; i < asTimestamps.length; i++){
                                String sTimestamp = asTimestamps[i].toString();
                                String sValue = asValues[i].toString();
                                Double dValue = Double.valueOf(sValue);

                                data.setValue(i, 0, dtf.parse(sTimestamp)); 
                                data.setValue(i, j+1, dValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }       
                    //Opciones de graficado
                    AnnotatedTimeLine.Options options = AnnotatedTimeLine.Options.create();
                    options.setDisplayAnnotations(true);
                    options.setDisplayZoomButtons(true);
                    options.setScaleType(AnnotatedTimeLine.ScaleType.ALLMAXIMIZE);
                    options.setLegendPosition(AnnotatedTimeLine.AnnotatedLegendPosition. NEW_ROW);
                    AnnotatedTimeLine atl = new AnnotatedTimeLine(data, options,"475px", "310px");
                    atlHorizontalPanel.add(atl);
                }

            };
            //The APO for visualization is loaded in order to show the graph
            VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback,AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE);
        }
    }
```

What I have found is that the first tab prints the graph, however, the remaining tabs don't load the graphs at all. Do you know what reason could be causing this misbehaviour?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=217&can=1&q=tab&colspec=ID%20Type%20API%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) which might be related.

I think it is not possible to draw/create a chart inside a hidden container and then make the container visible afterwards.

The chart will only render properly if you draw/create it inside a visible container that is attached to the `DOM`.

There is a workaround for the `TabPanel`:

```
@UiHandler("tabPanel")
void handleSelect(SelectionEvent<Integer> e) {
    /* redraw only when switching to tab that contains visualization */
    if (e.getSelectedItem() == 1) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                drawVisualization();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would also recommed to use the unofficial [gwt-charts](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/) wrapper instead of the outdated official `gwt-visualization` wrapper. This will fix all issues and also properly resize the charts.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, if I understood correctly, I should print the first tab and, then, include an event handler in the TabPanel object with the aim of re-printing the screen when the selected tab changes, right?

Comment: yes, thast should fix your problem Or you use the `gwt-charts` which should handle this issues.